# How to modify react/jsx-no-useless-fragment rule to allow <>{children}</>

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-fragment

I am all for getting rid of useless React Fragments `<><Element /></>` from my codebase and the ESLint rule `react/jsx-no-useless-fragment` is great for catching this.

However, there are repetitive cases where the Fragment is not useless, specifically for `return <>{children}</>`, this scenario is my desired output in a few cases throughout my codebase.

Is there a way to configure the `react/jsx-no-useless-fragment` rule to keep working in general and have it not raise warnings in scenarios where the case is `<>{children}</>`?

Note: I'm not looking to call `// eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-useless-fragment` above every scenario (that is already my current workaround).

Comment: You have the [`allowExpressions`](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md#allowexpressions) option for that

Comment: @Fraction thank you that worked perfectly for me, if you write an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`allowExpressions`](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md#allowexpressions) option which allow expressions in a fragment

```
// Good
<>{children}</>
```